# Applying a filter to AudioContext

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I'm attempting to apply a low-pass filter to a sound I load and play through SoundJS.

Right now I'm attempting to do this like this:

```
    var audio = createjs.Sound.activePlugin;
    var source = audio.context.createBufferSource();
    // Create the filter
    var filter = audio.context.createBiquadFilter();
    // Create the audio graph.
    source.connect(filter);
    filter.connect(audio.context.destination);
    // Create and specify parameters for the low-pass filter.
    filter.type = 0; // Low-pass filter. See BiquadFilterNode docs
    filter.frequency.value = 440; // Set cutoff to 440 HZ
    // Playback the sound.
    createjs.Sound.play("Song");
```

But I'm not having much luck. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I built the [MusicVisualizer demo](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos/visualizer) one of the interesting limitations I found was that all of the audio nodes had to be built using the same context to work.  You can access the SoundJS context via `createjs.WebAudioPlugin.context`

You'll also need to connect your filter into the existing node flow if you want it to work as expected.  You can see the MusicVisualizer demo on [github](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/blob/master/examples/MusicVisualizer.html) if you want to review the source, which does this.  You can also review the [documentation](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/classes/WebAudioPlugin.html) online, which might be helpful.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I actually figured it out by looking at the source of your visualizer before you posted this but nice to have the github link too.